# PHP such as stripslashes for forward slash?

Tags: php, stripslashes

Is there a similar option for removing forward slashes?

I have a text input that could be any manner of slashes:

e.g */slug/* or */slug* or *slug* or *slug/*

I need to completely remove all forward slashes regardless of where they are. I know `stripslashes` will do this for \ slashes. Is there anything similar for forward?

Currently I have:

```
$successful_slug = stripslashes($input_successful_slug);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove them using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace)

```
$successful_slug = str_replace('/', '', $input_successful_slug);
```

If you want to remove only leading and trailing slashes (and leave those inside the string), use [`trim`](http://php.net/trim)

```
$successful_slug = trim($input_successful_slug, '/');
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the better solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Just replace forward slash `"/"` with an empty string `""`:

```
$processed_slug = 
    str_replace(
        $search  = '/', 
        $replace = '', 
        $subject = $input_successful_slug
    )
;
```

See *[`str_replace(php)`](https://php.net/str_replace)*.

Comment: I believe that you need to escape that `"\"` : `"\\"`